# Implement parallel computation for fetching team's Data

Tags: c#, async-await

I am creating an App where I fetch post and comments from Teams. Previously I was using for loop and fetching details each time i am member of one by one, As I am member of more than 40-50 teams, It's taking lot of time to fetch the comments and posts.

I am trying to apply some parallelism in the code:

```
 public async Task<Package> getTeamsPostData(Teams team,string token)
    {
        Package pkgTeam = new Package();
   
        //some computation to fetch post and comment of this team
        //Some await functions is also called from this section

        return pkgTeam;
    }

    public async Task<Package> GetTeamsCommentsAndChannelActivityByDate(string Date, string token,List<Teams> teams)
    {
   
            var taskArray = teams.Select(t => Task.Factory.StartNew(() => getTeamsPostData(t, token))).ToArray();

            //then wait for all tasks to complete asyncronously
            Task.WaitAll(taskArray);

            //then add the result of all the tasks to r in a treadsafe fashion
            var r = taskArray.Select(task => task.Result).ToList();


        return r;
    }
```

I have done above changes to implement parallel processing, but in result I am getting Status as **Waiting for Activation** and i am not getting any post and comment data in the result.
Also it is not taking any time for executing ***WaitAll*** method

Comment: you should definitely check out my answer.

Comment: `Task.Factory.StartNew` is a low-level method with surprising default behavior. Use `Task.Run` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code can't be compiled because `GetTeamsCommentsAndChannelActivityByDate()` method returns `List<Task<Package>>` but your method signature return type is `Task<Package>`.

Your problem probably occurs because your `Select()` returns `IEnumerable<Task<Task<T>>>` instead of `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`. Then in the `Task.WaitAll(taskArray)` line you are waiting for the `Task<Task<T>>` instead of each inner task.

You can use `Unwrap()` method to resolve your problem. `Unwrap()` allows to create a proxy Task that represents the entire asynchronous operation. Example of use:

```
var taskArray = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    return i;
}).Unwrap()).ToArray();


Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
```

In your case:

```
var taskArray = teams.Select(t => Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await getTeamsPostData(t, token)).Unwrap()).ToArray();
```

You can also use `Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew()` when you don't need configuration as @Jiya suggested. It unwraps asynchronous operation automatically under the hood.